# What is wrong with my code about swimming?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It's me again, from like an hour ago.
So I was messing around with some of the answers that I was provided with and well this is what I got now:

```py
import random


while != "No":
    print("Would you like to get your set?")
    choice = input("Yes or No: ")
    if choice == 'Yes:
        print(swimming())
    else:
        break


def swimming():

    def stroke():
        x = random.randint(1, 150)
        if x < 51:
            print("Freestyle")
        elif x >51 and x<100:
            print("Breaststroke")
        else:
            print("Butterfly")

    def laps():
        i = random.randint(1, 300)
        if i <= 99:
            print("Ten Laps")
        elif i >=100 and i <= 199:
            print("Fifteen Laps")
        else:
            print("Twenty Laps")

    def style():
        j = random.randint(0,15)
        if j < 5:
            print("Paddles")
        elif j > 6 and j < 10:
            print("Bouy")
        else:
            print("Kick-Board")
```

I currently get an error in my command line saying that "!=" is an invalid syntax and can not be run.
Would this code at all work or is there something I can do to fix it?
Sorry about my code, I barely started to learn it a week ago.

Comment: `if choice == 'Yes:` missing `'`

Comment: It is still focused n the "!="

Comment: That is because `while != "No":` is incorrect, you either put some `var` in it like `while x != 'No':` or run a infinite loop and break on a condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while != "No":
```

is an incomplete condition, you need to change it to something like:

```
while True: # so the loop only ends/breaks on a condition inside it
```

Also, You have a missing `'` in the line:

```
if choice == 'Yes:
```

Change it to:

```
if choice == 'Yes':
```

EDIT:

you need to define the `swimming()` method before the loop:

```
import random
    
def swimming():

    def stroke():
        x = random.randint(1, 150)
        if x < 51:
            print("Freestyle")
        elif x >51 and x<100:
            print("Breaststroke")
        else:
            print("Butterfly")

    def laps():
        i = random.randint(1, 300)
        if i <= 99:
            print("Ten Laps")
        elif i >=100 and i <= 199:
            print("Fifteen Laps")
        else:
            print("Twenty Laps")

    def style():
        j = random.randint(0,15)
        if j < 5:
            print("Paddles")
        elif j > 6 and j < 10:
            print("Bouy")
        else:
            print("Kick-Board")
        
    while True:
        print("Would you like to get your set?")
        choice = input("Yes or No: ")
        if choice == 'Yes':
            print(swimming())
        else:
            break
```

Also, this would return `None` as you are not calling any method inside the `swimming()` method or returning anything.

So you can call the methods inside like:

```
def swimming():
    def stroke():
        x = random.randint(1, 150)
        if x < 51:
            print("Freestyle")
        elif x >51 and x<100:
            print("Breaststroke")
        else:
            print("Butterfly")

    def laps():
        i = random.randint(1, 300)
        if i <= 99:
            print("Ten Laps")
        elif i >=100 and i <= 199:
            print("Fifteen Laps")
        else:
            print("Twenty Laps")

    def style():
        j = random.randint(0,15)
        if j < 5:
            print("Paddles")
        elif j > 6 and j < 10:
            print("Bouy")
        else:
            print("Kick-Board")
    stroke()
    laps()
    style()
```

Comment: This seemed to fix it now I am having a problem with it saying that "swimming()" is not defined, would you happen to know why?

Comment: @OliverPomaranski you need to define the `swimming()` method before the `while` loop. Check the edit

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```py
import random

def swimming():
    def stroke():
        x = random.randint(1, 150)
        if x < 51:
            print("Freestyle")
        elif x >51 and x<100:
            print("Breaststroke")
        else:
            print("Butterfly")

    def laps():
        i = random.randint(1, 300)
        if i <= 99:
            print("Ten Laps")
        elif i >=100 and i <= 199:
            print("Fifteen Laps")
        else:
            print("Twenty Laps")

    def style():
        j = random.randint(0,15)
        if j < 5:
            print("Paddles")
        elif j > 6 and j < 10:
            print("Bouy")
        else:
            print("Kick-Board")
    stroke()
    laps()
    style()

while True:
    print("Would you like to get your set?")
    choice = input("Yes or No: ")
    if choice == 'Yes':
        swimming()
    else:
        break
```